# How can I encrypt files in GPG with password under dot

Tags: gnupg

Just wondering, how can I encrypt files with GPG with password under dot?

I have a file called `test.txt` and I want to encrypt this file into GPG with password, so this is the script I wrote to encrypt the file:

```
gpg - c test.txt
```

then it is asking for the Passphrase and I entered abc123. File `test.txt.gpg` was generated as a result.

Then I tried to decrypt the gpg file by using the following script under dot:

```
gpg -o testing.txt -d test.txt.gpg
```

It decrypted the file for me without asking for the password (abc123).

Does anyone know where is going wrong with my encrypt?

Comment: Something's very weird with your encryption command. Are you really running `- c`, or `-c` instead, or something completely different?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.